# metal looking ball dust in attic, dangerous?

Tags: insulation, attic, metal, old-house

I was installing insulation in our attic. On the beams, there was this metal looking ball dust. Any clue what it is? Was exposed to by breathing it breifly, then skin contact for a few hours. I have not been able to sleep all night so Im hoping i didnt poision myself [image]

Comment: I doubt it's mercury but if you're concerned it will be immediately obvious if you poke it with a stick or try and pick one up with needle nose pliers. Mercury is a liquid and will squish around. Metal slag is a solid. You'll know.

Answer (score 2):

A plasma cutter used for cutting HVAC duct will have this kind of debris not dangerous. Other than that possibly conduit or other metal pipe / brackets being cut leaves the filings or if with a torch the balls, but I would expect a plasma cutter with most modern homes and ductwork.

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely to be iron slag from mineral wool. You can see examples of this here:

https://inspectapedia.com/insulation/Rock-wool-microscope-identification.php#SlagWool

I have loose slag wool insulation from the early 20th century in the attic of my home. All throughout the material, there are these similar metallic balls encapsulated in the insulation, and a significant amount of these same bits that have settled to the bottom of the joist cavity over time.

The bits you're seeing are likely just beads of iron. Slag wool was manufactured from iron slag:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral_wool#History

> The process involved blowing a strong stream of air across a falling flow of liquid iron slag

You can test whether this is likely iron by just passing a magnet over it to see if it sticks. If it does, it's a ferrous material, and considering the location, is likely to be iron slag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It could be electronics soldering, being that shiny. Which, could have lead, but lead poisoning effects only last a day. Though, I'd probably be much more on the side of harmless metal grinding and cutting debris. It could be from the attic area if there's ductwork, steel studs or beams or if there was renovation of the roof or something where lots of nails were cut.

Comment: Thanks. I used to work in a neon sign lab and we used mercury. It looked too closr for comfort. It is suspicious how it forms in those metal balls...

Comment: Mercury would be runny, if in ball form...as far as I know. Balls usually means high heat and was temporarily molten. You can wet rag it away if you're concerned about dusting or that brooming or vacuuming would put too much into the air. Home Builders are slobs :)